# From PFQueryTableView to UICollectionView example

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, parse-platform

I have to ask if this is possible before trying to do it.

I have a PFQueryTableView that fetches data from Parse.com and I need the cell to segue into a UICollectionView (passing the data of course). Is this possible? If so, how would I go about? Does anyone know of a similar example or tutorial I could follow?

I believe that passing the data would be the same as for a normal View Controller (hopefully) but my concern would be in loading the cell. I need to pass multiple images and since I'll be using a PFImageView inside the cell to load the image I would have to use the loadInBackground method. But how would I set the cell to be reusable? Please Help! and Thank You Very much for you time!!!

Comment: As i understand there are 3 separate steps
1. Fetch data from parse.com
2. Passing the data between viewcontrollers
3. Displaying the data from parse.com
You can fetch the data from parse.com meanwhile you can show an UIIndicatorView in your PFQueryTableView and once you get the async response / delegate methods saying fetch done you can call the UIColloectionView controller with the data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is surely possible. Depending on how you have the data in your PFQueryTableView, you can pass mostly any kind of data to the UICollectionView.

The way to make a reusable cell for the collection view is similar to a table view:

```
UICollectionReusableView *collView = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```